# ことがある vs. ものだ when talking about the past

Tags: grammar, meaning, words

Small doubt about this phrase from Bunpro:

> 子供のころ、この喫茶店に**行ったことがある**。あの時のドーナツは、何とうまかったことか。

Wouldn't it feel better as:

> 子供のころ、この喫茶店に**来たものだ**。あの時のドーナツは、何とうまかったことか。

Just my two cents, the whole idea of "I used to come here" feels better this way in my opinion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

行ったことがある means "I **have been** there." I believe it's different from "I **used to** go there," which 行ったものだ would mean. The former states your past experience and it could be a one-time visit, whereas the latter is used when you think back to your past habit.

Whether to use 行く or 来る depends on where the speaker is saying this at. The original sentence supposes the speaker is looking at a photo or something when they refer to the coffee shop as この喫茶店 and they are not actually there. Then the verb must be 行く.